# Parsing JSON Data from AP with Swift 5

Tags: ios, json, api, structure, swift5

I am trying to parse this json file

```
{
    "Global Quote": {
        "01. symbol": "AAPL",
        "02. open": "122.6000",
        "03. high": "123.3500",
        "04. low": "121.5400",
        "05. price": "121.7800",
        "06. volume": "79075988",
        "07. latest trading day": "2020-12-14",
        "08. previous close": "122.4100",
        "09. change": "-0.6300",
        "10. change percent": "-0.5147%"
    } }
```

I want to parse his JSON text but am not quite sure why my structure is not filling  this global quote object but instead leaves it empty it empty.

```
struct GlobalQuote: Codable{
    
    var symbol: String?
    var open: String?
    var high: String?
    var low: String?
    var price: String?
    var volume: String?
    var latestTradingDay: String?
    var previousClose: String?
    var change: String?
    var changepercent: String?
    
    private enum codingKeys : String, CodingKey {
         case symbol = "01. symbol"
         case open = "02. open"
         case high = "03. high"
        case low = "04. low"
        case price = "05. price"
        case volume = "06.volume"
        case latestTradingDay = "07. latest trading day"
        case previousClose = "08. previous close"
        case change = "09. change"
        case changepercent = "10. change percent"
        
    
      }
    

}
```

...It is returns this in the console..

```
GlobalQuote(symbol: nil, open: nil, high: nil, low: nil, price: nil, volume: nil, latestTradingDay: nil, previousClose: nil, change: nil, changepercent: nil)
```

...Not really sure why I am not receiving my data.

Comment: Could you please add the code where you parse the json?

Answer (score 0):

To decode your JSON you first need to change the `codingKeys` inner enum of `GlobalQuote` struct to `CodingKeys`. (start with upper case)

Then you either need another struct to represent the outer JSON object like this:

```
struct ResponseGlobalQuote: Codable {
    var globalQuote: GlobalQuote
    
    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case globalQuote = "Global Quote"
    }
}

let decoder = JSONDecoder()
do {
    let decoded = try decoder.decode(ResponseGlobalQuote.self, from: data)
    print(decoded)
} catch {
    print(error)
}
```

or modify your decoding to use `[String: GlobalQuote]` as the decoding type:

```
let decoder = JSONDecoder()
do {
    let decoded = try decoder.decode([String: GlobalQuote].self, from: Data(jsonString.utf8))
    print(decoded.values.first)
} catch {
    print(error)
}
```